# newbie: error message when 'rake -T'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rake, rake-task

I am using **Ruby Enterprise Edition** for my project. When I check all my **rake task** by run the command `rake -T` , I got the following error message:

```
You have already activated rake 0.9.2.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.2. Using bundle exec may solve this.
```

The error message implies that I can use **bundle exec** to solve the problem, but I am not sure how?  So, how to get rid of this error message?

**------------------------------ more ---------------------------**

I prefer to update my **Gemfile** instead of run `bundle exec rake -T`. But when I open my project Gemfile, I did not see rake 0.9.2 in my Gemfile, why the error message complains that I have it? Where could be the place I defined rake 0.9.2??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run `bundle exec rake -T`, this ensures that the version of rake that is specified in your Gemfile is running, not another version.

Alternatively, update your Gemfile.

Comment: I prefer to update my Gemfile, but I dont have rake 0.9.2 in my Gemfile, why the error message complain that I have it? Where could be the place I defined rake 0.9.2??

Comment: Mellon, check your Gemfile.lock. You probably updated rake after running `bundle install`. Run `bundle update rake` to update the Gemfile.lock.

Comment: Harald, Thanks, it now works. Could you also please explain to me why rake is not defined in my Gemfile but in Gemfile.lock? Isn't it a gem?

Comment: Mellon, Gemfile describes the immediate dependencies your project depends on. Gemfile.lock records the actual versions of those dependencies and all dependencies of those again. This is to allow `bundle install` to recreate your exact environment so you don't get any unpleasant surprises when deploying your app.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `rake` tool does not match the version written in the `Gemfile`.

You first need to run this command, to ensure rake 0.9.2 get installed:

```
bundle install
```

Then, you can run rake 0.9.2 with the following command:

```
bundle exec rake -T
```

The `bundle` thing is a nice tool to help you manage the dependency of your application. You can get more info from [here](http://gembundler.com/).