# rake issue that still persists after trying other suggested solutions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I am going through a tutorial and have an issue with rake db:migrate and my gemfile.  I KNOW there are several answers, and this question is asked (and answered a lot) here.  But for some reason, I am either running in circles, confused or maybe something else is going on that I'm not aware of.

I've tried the answer referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050276/newbie-error-message-when-rake-t) -- where I ran

```
bundle exec run rake -T
```

That did not seem to work.

Then I tried to follow dhh's advice referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199301/global-access-to-rake-dsl-methods-is-deprecated), but my system is saying that I don't have the gemfile to uninstall.  Here is what I did:

```
Z-Kidds-MacBook-Air:demo_app zkidd$ rake --version
rake, version 0.9.2.2
Z-Kidds-MacBook-Air:demo_app zkidd$ gem uninstall rake -v=0.9.2.2
INFO:  gem "rake" is not installed
Z-Kidds-MacBook-Air:demo_app zkidd$
```

Anyways, here is the read-out when I run trace:

> Z-Kidds-MacBook-Air:demo_app zkidd$ rake db:migrate --trace
>   rake aborted!
>   You have already activated rake 0.9.2.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.8.7. Using bundle exec may solve this.
>   /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup'
>   /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:17:in`setup'
>   /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:110:in `setup'
>   /Users/zkidd/rails_projects/demo_app/config/boot.rb:8:in`'
>   /Users/zkidd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
>   /Users/zkidd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
>   /Users/zkidd/rails_projects/demo_app/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
>   /Users/zkidd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
>   /Users/zkidd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
>   /Users/zkidd/rails_projects/demo_app/Rakefile:4:in`'
>   /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
>   /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in`load_rakefile'
>   /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
>   /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in`block in load_rakefile'
>   /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
>   /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in`load_rakefile'
>   /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in `block in run'
>   /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in`standard_exception_handling'
>   /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
>   /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in`'
>   /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/bin/rake:19:in `load'
>   /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/bin/rake:19:in`'

I also tried to modify my Gemfile by adding

```
gem "rake", "0.9.2.2"
```

But then I get this:

Z-Kidds-MacBook-Air:first_app zkidd$ rake db:migrate
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/task' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
    at /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb
WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please include
    ...  Rake::DSL into classes and modules which use the Rake DSL methods.
WARNING: DSL method FirstApp::Application#task called at /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:214:in `initialize_tasks'
Z-Kidds-MacBook-Air:first_app zkidd$

And I am running:

Rails 3.0.1

Answer (score 0):

In your Gemfile, set the version for rake to from 0.8.7 to 0.9.2.2:

```
gem "rake", "0.9.2.2"
```

Then run your update:

```
bundle update
```

I actually just solved this issue earlier today in one of my own projects.

Comment: tried that, but it did not work.  I got a WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated. message -- I added this into the question section

Comment: I am getting a global deprecated message even when I do that :-/

Comment: What version of rails are you running? I just did a quick google search, and this might be a bug with an older version of Rails 3. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702504/rails-how-do-i-resolve-the-rake-rdoctask-is-deprecated-warning

Comment: Yeah, than you have the bug in the older version of rails. Upgrading to at least rails 3.0.9 should fix the problem.